# Mobility in Forms in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm using the the gem [Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) to translate attributes in Models.

However, I also need to translate some attributes in a Form, ej.

```
 class SpecsForm
  include ActiveAttr::Model

  class CombustionEngineForm
    include ActiveAttr::Model

    attribute :type, default: 'combustion', type: String
    attribute :engine_name, type: String
    attribute :fuel_type, type: String
    attribute :max_horsepower, type: String
    attribute :max_torque, type: String
    attribute :cubic_capacity, type: Integer
    attribute :tank_capacity, type: Integer
    attribute :consumption_city, type: Float
    attribute :consumption_highway, type: Float
    attribute :consumption_combined, type: Float
  end
```

But when I write

```
    extend Mobility
    translates :engine_name, backend: :key_value, type: :string
```

I get an error the following error

**The error I get is undefined method `has_many' for Catalog::Versions::SpecsForm::ElectricEngineForm:Class**

could anybody help? Thankss!

Comment: Where do you write `extend Mobility...`? What error do you get?

Comment: I tried writing it under include ActiveAttr::Model for both clases.

The error I get is
undefined method `has_many' for Catalog::Versions::SpecsForm::ElectricEngineForm:Class

Comment: The examples in the Mobility readme show that Mobility is used to extend `ApplicationRecord` class.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not using `ApplicationRecord`, but I'm using a `Form` which includes `include ActiveAttr::Model`. I don't think they are the same thing

Comment: Then you cannot use Mobility because its readme tells that it requires `ActiveRecord >= 5.0`.